# Windows Security (In windows 7) keeps asking for my credentials, and won't "Remember my credentials"

Tags: security, windows-7

I'm not the network admin, but my network admin is having trouble solving this as well.

My issue is exactly as the title says...

*Windows Security (In windows 7) keeps asking for my credentials, and won't "Remember my credentials"*

Even if I check mark the box that says "Remember my credentials", I'll eventually be prompted to enter my credentials again.

I am an administrator for this computer.

Please let me know if there's any other details I can provide!
[image]

Comment: So I have a couple questions for you:
Is your computer on the domain you are connecting to? How high is your UAC? If you are on the domain it may be a group policy that you must enter your password to access the domain or you are trying to access a file that you don't have rights to. You may want to try the solution posted on SuperUser http://superuser.com/questions/263743/windows-7-never-remembers-my-password-credential Hope that helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to find the solution at this forum

http://www.w7forums.com/windows-7-does-not-save-network-login-credentials-username-and-password-t1621p3.html

Essentially go to the Windows Vault (Store credentials for automatic logon), and edit the credentials there.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 1):

This is a issue with your Windows Credential Manager. Moste likely because your credential manager have wrong entry with and old password or if it was selected to be disable.

Write **Credential Manager** at the start menu and open it. Check if it is allowing save password and if it is delete all the entries saved and try again. If it's not allowing to save password it's possible that it is setting from a domain groupo policy and your network admin should check it.

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

None of these aforementioned methods solved my Win7 remembering credentials problem. However, after many trials, I discovered that the problem was caused by the remote device's computer name coinciding with one of its local user names! I changed the computer name to something different than all of the local user names, then entered my remote credentials and enabled "remember my credentials" once again. After that Win7 never asks me again to logon for access to the remote computer.

Answer (score 1):

For windows7, Go to control panel -> credential manager, there you will get Windows credentials, Generic credentials, select each option and click on remove from vault to delete old saved passwords and check now, it will not ask again for username nad password!

Comment: Isn't this the same instruction as the accepted answer?

Comment: @jornane this is a slightly different answer; it suggests _deleting_ the credentials, which worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

What are you connecting to?

If this is a Remote Desktop session, there might be a policy in place to disallow saving logon credentials: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee791914(v=ws.10).aspx.